# Can't browse folders on SMB share on Mac without 5-10 minute delay

Tags: mac, freeze, samba, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 R2 file server setup with two shares, A & B, over SMB. Browsing share A works fine. When Mac users try to browse through or open documents on share B, their Finder window freezes, pinwheel pops up, and they are stuck like this for upwards of 5 to 10 minutes. I am perplexed as to what may be causing this error.

In all of the affected users `system.log` in their Console.app (despite not being where these messages are stored anymore (see log(1)), I see this error repeatedly logged hundreds of times when they browse the file share:

```
opendirectoryd mbr_identifier_translate failed with result Not Found
opendirectoryd mbr_identifier_translate failed with result Not Found
opendirectoryd mbr_identifier_translate failed with result Not Found
opendirectoryd mbr_identifier_translate failed with result Not Found
```

And under the Activities view in Console.app

```
Finder  Membership API: translate identifier
Finder  Membership API: translate identifier
Finder  Membership API: translate identifier
Finder  Membership API: translate identifier
```

And also (even though these may be unrelated):

```
ps         Retrieve User by ID
ps         Retrieve User by ID
ps         Retrieve User by ID
ps         Retrieve User by ID
```

After seeing these errors, I thought it may be the Mac's SMB cache causing the issue, so I disabled it for the affected users referencing [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207520) from Apple's website. However, it did not have any effect, and the freezes persist.

We then thought it may be VSS errors on our file server which is running out of space, so we disabled VSS entirely. However, the freezes keep happening.

Does the fault lie within our file server or our network? Is it related to Apple's implementation of SMB? Is it some common software each user has that is causing the issue? Has anyone else experienced this? It is driving me mad trying to figure it out. Any insight would be appreciated.

All clients are using SMB v3. All Macs are running 10.13.6.

Comment: My first question would be which version of SMB you are using.  Besides the fact SMBv1 is insecure.  Different versions of SMB are slower than SMBv3

Comment: It looks like clients are negotiating with SMB 3.02.

Comment: What version of macOS? Does the problem still happen with Mojave? Are the Macs set up to bind to the ActiveDirectory domain?

Comment: Is the file server a member of an Active Directory domain? Can Windows-based machines access the shares without trouble? Does the delay happen if you use a different logon account for the server?

Comment: I assume Share A works fine based on your second sentence. If that's the case, what's different about that share?

Comment: @Spiff all macs are on 10.13.6. We do not wish to upgrade to Mojave at this time. All Macs are AD bound via Centrify.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes it is a domain member. Windows based machines have no issues. I have tried other accounts from my own Mac, and do not experience the issue.

Comment: @DawnBenton - Yes. I am not sure they are any different. They are both on the same server and same storage device.

Comment: When you say you've tried other accounts, does that mean only one or a specific account is having this problem?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No, several users are experiencing the issue. All different accounts. About 4 in total.

Comment: OK. Any Mac users *not* experiencing the issue? Does creating a brand-new Windows user on the server and using that from the Mac make any difference?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It doesn't happen for me on my Mac, but currently users are connected to the shares automatically at login. We can try modifying this GPO to use new credentials for these specific users to connect...maybe there is an issue with Centrify/permissions/the way it is applying it.

Comment: I'm only suggesting a new user for testing purposes...to help determine if the problem is with the user accounts being used to authenticate to the server or something else.